# Keras CNN training to recognize captcha: Get low loss and get low accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to train a model which can recognize the captcha like this

[image: captcha]

I want to recognize each of the word in the picture

so I create the cnn model below

first I have a model like this:

```
print("Creating CNN model...")
a = Input((40, 80, 3))
out = a
out = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
#out = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
#out = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
#out = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out) 
out = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2) , dim_ordering="th")(out)
out = Flatten()(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = Dense(512, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = [Dense(36, name='digit1', activation='softmax')(out),\
       Dense(36, name='digit2', activation='softmax')(out),\
       Dense(36, name='digit3', activation='softmax')(out),\
       Dense(36, name='digit4', activation='softmax')(out)]

model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

[image: layer]

When I am training the model
I think that it has a high loss but not really bad accuracy on valid set

like this:

```
Epoch 47/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9421 - digit1_loss: 0.2456 - digit2_loss: 0.2657 - digit3_loss: 0.2316 - digit4_loss: 0.1992 - digit1_acc: 0.9400 - digit2_acc: 0.9190 - digit3_acc: 0.9330 - digit4_acc: 0.9300 - val_loss: 5.0476 - val_digit1_loss: 0.5545 - val_digit2_loss: 1.8687 - val_digit3_loss: 1.8951 - val_digit4_loss: 0.7294 - val_digit1_acc: 0.8300 - val_digit2_acc: 0.5500 - val_digit3_acc: 0.5200 - val_digit4_acc: 0.8000

Epoch 00047: val_digit4_acc did not improve from 0.83000
Epoch 48/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9154 - digit1_loss: 0.1681 - digit2_loss: 0.2992 - digit3_loss: 0.2556 - digit4_loss: 0.1924 - digit1_acc: 0.9520 - digit2_acc: 0.9180 - digit3_acc: 0.9220 - digit4_acc: 0.9370 - val_loss: 4.6983 - val_digit1_loss: 0.4929 - val_digit2_loss: 1.8220 - val_digit3_loss: 1.6665 - val_digit4_loss: 0.7170 - val_digit1_acc: 0.8700 - val_digit2_acc: 0.5300 - val_digit3_acc: 0.5900 - val_digit4_acc: 0.8300

Epoch 00048: val_digit4_acc improved from 0.83000 to 0.83000, saving model to cnn_model.hdf5
Epoch 49/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.8703 - digit1_loss: 0.1813 - digit2_loss: 0.2374 - digit3_loss: 0.2537 - digit4_loss: 0.1979 - digit1_acc: 0.9450 - digit2_acc: 0.9240 - digit3_acc: 0.9250 - digit4_acc: 0.9400 - val_loss: 4.6405 - val_digit1_loss: 0.4936 - val_digit2_loss: 1.8665 - val_digit3_loss: 1.5744 - val_digit4_loss: 0.7060 - val_digit1_acc: 0.8700 - val_digit2_acc: 0.5000 - val_digit3_acc: 0.5900 - val_digit4_acc: 0.7800

Epoch 00049: val_digit4_acc did not improve from 0.83000
Epoch 50/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9112 - digit1_loss: 0.2036 - digit2_loss: 0.2543 - digit3_loss: 0.2222 - digit4_loss: 0.2312 - digit1_acc: 0.9360 - digit2_acc: 0.9170 - digit3_acc: 0.9290 - digit4_acc: 0.9330 - val_loss: 4.9354 - val_digit1_loss: 0.5632 - val_digit2_loss: 1.8869 - val_digit3_loss: 1.7899 - val_digit4_loss: 0.6954 - val_digit1_acc: 0.8600 - val_digit2_acc: 0.5000 - val_digit3_acc: 0.5700 - val_digit4_acc: 0.7900
```

then I use model.evaluate on valid set and I get the loss and accuracy like this:

(Loss is high and accuracy is high too)

```
Test loss: 4.9354219818115235
Test accuracy: 0.5632282853126526
```

second, I change the model like this:(take out 2 hidden layer)

```
# Create CNN Model
print("Creating CNN model...")
a = Input((40, 80, 3))
out = a
out = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
#out = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
#out = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
#out = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out) 
out = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
out = BatchNormalization()(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2) , dim_ordering="th")(out)
out = Flatten()(out)
out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
#out = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(out)
#out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
#out = Dense(512, activation='relu')(out)
#out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
out = [Dense(36, name='digit1', activation='softmax')(out),\
       Dense(36, name='digit2', activation='softmax')(out),\
       Dense(36, name='digit3', activation='softmax')(out),\
       Dense(36, name='digit4', activation='softmax')(out)]

model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.summary()
```

[image: layer2]

When I am training the model
I think that it has a low loss and good accuracy on valid set

like this:

```
Epoch 47/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0536 - digit1_loss: 0.0023 - digit2_loss: 0.0231 - digit3_loss: 0.0230 - digit4_loss: 0.0052 - digit1_acc: 1.0000 - digit2_acc: 0.9980 - digit3_acc: 0.9990 - digit4_acc: 0.9990 - val_loss: 1.2679 - val_digit1_loss: 0.1059 - val_digit2_loss: 0.6560 - val_digit3_loss: 0.4402 - val_digit4_loss: 0.0658 - val_digit1_acc: 0.9600 - val_digit2_acc: 0.8200 - val_digit3_acc: 0.8900 - val_digit4_acc: 0.9900

Epoch 00047: val_digit4_acc did not improve from 0.99000
Epoch 48/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0686 - digit1_loss: 0.0044 - digit2_loss: 0.0269 - digit3_loss: 0.0238 - digit4_loss: 0.0136 - digit1_acc: 0.9990 - digit2_acc: 0.9980 - digit3_acc: 0.9980 - digit4_acc: 0.9950 - val_loss: 1.2249 - val_digit1_loss: 0.1170 - val_digit2_loss: 0.6593 - val_digit3_loss: 0.4152 - val_digit4_loss: 0.0334 - val_digit1_acc: 0.9500 - val_digit2_acc: 0.8200 - val_digit3_acc: 0.8800 - val_digit4_acc: 0.9900

Epoch 00048: val_digit4_acc did not improve from 0.99000
Epoch 49/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0736 - digit1_loss: 0.0087 - digit2_loss: 0.0309 - digit3_loss: 0.0268 - digit4_loss: 0.0071 - digit1_acc: 0.9980 - digit2_acc: 0.9940 - digit3_acc: 0.9950 - digit4_acc: 0.9970 - val_loss: 1.3238 - val_digit1_loss: 0.1229 - val_digit2_loss: 0.6496 - val_digit3_loss: 0.4951 - val_digit4_loss: 0.0562 - val_digit1_acc: 0.9500 - val_digit2_acc: 0.8400 - val_digit3_acc: 0.8500 - val_digit4_acc: 0.9900

Epoch 00049: val_digit4_acc did not improve from 0.99000
Epoch 50/50
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0935 - digit1_loss: 0.0050 - digit2_loss: 0.0354 - digit3_loss: 0.0499 - digit4_loss: 0.0032 - digit1_acc: 0.9980 - digit2_acc: 0.9910 - digit3_acc: 0.9890 - digit4_acc: 0.9990 - val_loss: 1.7740 - val_digit1_loss: 0.1539 - val_digit2_loss: 0.9237 - val_digit3_loss: 0.6273 - val_digit4_loss: 0.0690 - val_digit1_acc: 0.9300 - val_digit2_acc: 0.7900 - val_digit3_acc: 0.8400 - val_digit4_acc: 0.9900
```

but when I use model.evaluate on valid set and I get the loss and accuracy like this:

(lower loss and lower accuracy)

```
Test loss: 1.773969256877899
Test accuracy: 0.1539082833379507
```

Why can't I get higher accuracy after getting lower loss?
Or something wrong when I use "evaluate" method?

Comment: Try to use a different approach to this problem. I'd suggest encoding an input image using a CNN as you do in your example, then using obtained fixed length embedding vectors as input to an RNN with LSTM units. The RNN will generate a fixed length, four in your case, character sequence. Here is a nice guide on how it could be implemented in Keras https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html

Comment: OK Thanks~ I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on the training data. To me, it looks like the model is over-trained. The second possible option is a problem with train-, cross-validation- and test-set.

Please check:
Are they really independent? Especially train and cross-validation set.
How large your sets are? If you have enough variance in cross-validation.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have checked that the training set and validation set are independent. I used about 1000 on training and about 100 on validation set. Are they too small to train the model?

Comment: It depends on the type of the problem.  In your case, I think is on the edge. 1000 isn't too much, especially if a shape of the characters are really changing across the set.  I would expect that maybe network didn't see enough data to generalize and maybe cross-validation is somehow correlated to the training set (similar type of letter corruption, a similar order of letters etc.), what can do cross-validation easier than evaluation.

Comment: You are able to evaluate cross-validation set, so I am expecting that the problem is in the data and not in the code (you probably evaluate cross-validation set the same way as the evaluation set). 

I am Ph.D. candidate focused on audio and text, so far I was only playing with picture processing for fun, so I can be still wrong.

Comment: Here is my approach to troubleshooting, what I would try (it independent on the type of the problem):

1. check histogram of character for train, cross-validation, and evaluation.
It should be balanced (especially train and cross-validation), or you will find some bias in data (what is wrong for training).
2.  check histogram of characters for every position. This is just to be sure that, you don't have every last character in the training set and cross-validation. This should be also balanced.

Comment: 3. jackknifing
mix all data together and create new training-, cross-validation, and evaluation-set and check the results.

Comment: If all points above fail and data are really correct as possible, I would focus on network topology.  Now,  Your topology looks fine to me. It does not make sense trying more complicated stuff, untill you will get something from this.Usually, complicated topology means more training data to generalize properly.

You probably know everything, what I wrote, I just wanted to be clear and complete :D

Sorry, my comment was too long, so I split it.